# Is it possible to centralize all Express routes outside of the app file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically, I want to avoid a situation where my main app file is flooded with a list of routes. I'm wondering whether it's possible to organize the routes for, say, users, clients, locations each to its own router file, and then have a sort of master router pull all of these files into my application's entry point (e.g., index.js/server.js/app.js).

I'm shooting for something that resembles this, if possible:

app.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const mainRouter = require('app/routes/main');

app.use(mainRouter);
```

main.js

```
const mainRouter = require('express').Router();

const usersRouter = require('./users');
const locationsRouter = require('./locations');

mainRouter.use('/users', usersRouter);
mainRouter.use('/locations', locationsRouter);

module.exports = mainRouter;
```

Comment: I've updated the question title to make it fit your new example better. Please make sure it is accurate.

Comment: Working and well documented advice compilation on organizing a medium-size express app https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure

Answer (score 2):

You can split your routes up into logical groups using `express.Router` objects. Each set of routes would be stored in the `/routes` directory with a name that reflects what types of routes its associated with, for example `clients.js`.

**/routes/clients.js**

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('clients/index', { clients: [] })
})

module.exports = router
```

These routes would then be imported into your `app.js` and registered with the app using the `app.use()` method. This method also allows you to assign a base URL that each group of imported routes will be nested under. Which is why you don't need to specify the full path in each of your routes (eg: `/details` instead of `/clients/details`).

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use('/clients', require('./routes/clients'))
```

Browse to `http://localhost/clients/` and it will return `views/clients/index.html` back to you. You'll notice that you can group your views in a similar structure.

Comment: I've updated the original post to hopefully provide a clearer sense as to what I mean.

Comment: With your updated example, yes, you can do exactly that. However, you might want to keep the base routes (the `app.use()` declarations) in the app.js since they'll sit right next to the `/static` routes.